# `fastboot oem unlock` results in unknown command (Alcatel 1s)

Tags: rooting, fastboot, bootloader-lock, alcatel

I have an old Alcatel 1s (5024d) with Android 9 and I wanted to try my hand at rooting it. I've been following a tutorial that's supposed to let me flash a `boot.img` patched by Magisk Manager.

I've enabled USB debugging and OEM unlocking in the developer options, installed the necessary drivers, and have downloaded the official `platform-tools` to be able to use `adb` and `fastboot`. Additionally, I also have the original cable that came with my phone.

I have zero problems finding my device with and `adb` with `fastboot`, but when I try to use `fastboot oem unlock` (when my phone is in fastboot mode and connected to my PC), it just shows

```
FAILED (remote: 'unknown cmd.')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

I have also tried `fastboot flashing unlock`, but that shows

```
FAILED (remote: 'Not implemet.')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

There's frustratingly little information about rooting this 1s version, so I'd be grateful for any advice on how to unlock the bootloader.

Comment: Try 1. Changing the cable 2. Port

Comment: @beeshyams I tried that, but nothing changed.

Comment: Try  `fastboot flashing unlock_critical`, some devices need that. Not sure about your device

Comment: Above should be **after**  `fastboot flashing unlock`

Comment: See the second last post here https://forum.xda-developers.com/alcatel-1/help/alcatel-1s-2019-5024d-root-t4104295/amp/

Comment: Tried them both, but nothing seems to be working. My boot.img actually comes from this post and it was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Your best bet would be XDA- it's not a very popular device , so unless someone has it here, you may not get help. All the best

Comment: https://www.droidwin.com/fix-failed-remote-unknown-command-error/#Check_the_OEM_Unlock_Toggle

Answer (score -1):

Minimal ADB Fastboot

For Alcatel 1S (5420J), the following commands unlock the bootloader:

```
adb devices
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot devices
fastboot oem unlock
```